# Power off External Hard Drive that has separate data and power cables

Tags: external-hard-drive, raspberry-pi

I modified the cable that my external hard drive has so that the data cable feeds into my raspberry pi and the power feeds into a usb charger, when i turn off the pi, the hard drive does not turn off, and when i power off the charger, it makes a small click and spin down noise. I'm not sure if it's safe to be turning it off like this everyday, can someone give me advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try telling the disk to stop before poweroff by sending this command:

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdX/device/delete
```

Where you replace `sdX` with whatever device name gets assigned to the hard drive.

On my system, I get this message in the `dmesg` output:

```
[270171.642196] sd 7:2:0:0: [sdh] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[270171.642346] sd 7:2:0:0: [sdh] Stopping disk
```

Comment: could umount also be used?

Comment: You should definitely umount first, and then send the delete command.